# Asp.net with RegularExpression problem

Tags: asp.net, jquery, validation

Greetings,
I'm try to do validation on a textbox input to validate a phone number.
I have an asp.net textbox and checkbox. The default is to validate a US phone number and when I check the checkbox I should change the RegularExpression and error message to validate an international phone using my own RegularExpression.
I have no problem validating the international phone but the problem is when validating the US phone number. I'm always getting an error message that it is invalid phone number.
I used different RegularExpression but did not work.

Please look at my code and advise me.

Regards,
!

```
.....................
ASP.net Code
.....................    

<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UpdateContact.aspx.cs" Inherits="IMAM_APPLICATION.UpdateContact" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
             ValidPhoneHome("#<%= chkIntphoneHome%>");
             $("#aspnetForm").validate({

             // debug: true,
             rules: {
                 "<%=txtHomePhone.UniqueID %>": {
                     phonehome: true
                 }

                 },
             errorElement: "mydiv",
             wrapper: "mydiv",  // a wrapper around the error message

             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                 offset = element.offset();
                 error.insertBefore(element)
                 error.addClass('message');  // add a class to the wrapper
                 error.css('position', 'absolute');
                 error.css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
                 error.css('top', offset.top - (element.height() / 2));

             }
         });
         })
    </script>

    <div id="mydiv">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIntphoneHome" runat="server" Text="Internation Code"
            Style="position: absolute; top: 620px; left: 700px;"
            onclick=" ValidPhoneHome(this)" />

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHomePhone" runat="server" Style="top: 650px; left: 700px;
            position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 128px" ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</asp:Content>            

.............................
js.js File  
...................
var RegularExpression;
var USAPhone = /(^[a-z]([a-z_\.]*)@([a-z_\.]*)([.][a-z]{3})$)|(^[a-z]([a-z_\.]*)@([a-z_\.]*)(\.[a-z]{3})(\.[a-z]{2})*$)/i;

var InterPhone = /^\d{9,12}$/;
var errmsg;

function ValidPhoneHome(sender) {
    if (sender.checked == true) {
        RegularExpression = InterPhone;
        errmsg = "Enter 9 to 12 numbers as international number";    
    }
    else {
        RegularExpression = USAPhone;
        errmsg = "Enter a valid number";
    }
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("phonehome", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || RegularExpression.test(value);
    }, errmsg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where you got it from, but your Regular expression is not going to validate US phone numbers.. It expects WAY too many latin characters, and barely any numbers.

In fact.... it looks like an **e-mail regex validation** :D
Please check your regex, and replace it with something valid.

You can use something like

> /^(0-9?)?((?[0-9]{3})?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})$/

Taken from here: http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=58
Valid numbers: `1-(123)-123-1234`, `123 123 1234`, `1-800-ALPHNUM`

or a more simple one

> /^(()?(787|939)()|-)?([0-9]{3})(-)?([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4})$/

Taken from: http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=641
Valid numbers: `(787)755-0114`, `939-315-0112`, `7879093849`

but you really need to find the regex that would be best used in your scenario.

Comment: Thank you Artiom for trying to help me.
The regex for usa phone number I used was from regex library and I tried few but did not work for me.
However, I used your regex but they did not work for me.
First one will give Syntax error in regex and second one did not work too and I still getting the error message that the phone is invalid.

Comment: Hey, I've updated my answer to make it work in js. Also added some examples of valid phone numbers, for these regular expressions..